# Cannot import a key generated using ssh-keygen

Tags: javascript, subtlecrypto

I am trying to import an ECDSA public key generated using the `ssh-keygen` command in order to verify signatures using the [subtle crypto module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/importKey). I am getting an error, but without any details.

The command I'm using to generate the key:

```
ssh-keygen -t ecdsa
```

And the public key looks like this:

```
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBNBCvx3dHLrP0cXR0Iev5laJombKI7N4ND4wXdnwACrs5q2x1zIT9Adf9QtyVkc61acE1xzQ6sqnELAzw511cBM=
```

Here's a minimal snippet to reproduce the issue. It's a file input that reads the public key as an ArrayBuffer and tries to load it using the `importKey()` method.

```js
const loadKey = async (data) => {
    const key = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
        'raw',
        data,
        {
            name: 'ECDSA',
            namedCurve: 'P-256',
        },
        false,
        ['verify']
    )
    
    return key
}

const awaitedFR = async (file) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader()
    reader.addEventListener('load', ({target}) => resolve(target.result))
    reader.addEventListener('error', reject)
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)
});

(async () => {
    const _main = document.querySelector('main')

    const fileInput = document.createElement('input')
    fileInput.type = 'file'
    fileInput.addEventListener('change', async ({target}) => {
        const file = target.files[0]
        const res = await awaitedFR(file)
        console.log(res)
        try {
            const key = await loadKey(res)
            _main.innerHTML += 'Succesfully loaded public key'
        } catch (error) {
            _main.innerHTML += 'Failed to load public key: ' + JSON.stringify(error)
        }
        console.log(key)
    })

    _main.appendChild(fileInput)
})();
```

```html
<main></main>
```

Using the browser devtools I can see that the ArrayBuffer is correctly loaded in memory and the curve is properly set in the `importKey()` [`EcKeyImportParams.curve` parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EcKeyImportParams) (ssh-keygen defaults to NIST-P256).

I have no clue as of why this does not work, the script just fails silently. I also tried to export the key as PKCS#8 (and changing the `format` argument of the `importKey()` method) but to no avail.

There is no problem using keypairs generated directly in the browser though, my guess so far would be a formatting issue.